# Understanding weak reference counter

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

When creating shared_ptr it's manager object uses strong & weak reference counters. I understand that by using strong reference counter shared_ptr knows when to deallocate the managed object but I don't understand why is it using weak reference counter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two objects associated with `shared_ptr<T>` & `weak_ptr<T>`:

- the actual object (`T`)
- the control block, that contains the shared and weak counters

The actual object will be destroyed, if the *shared counter* reaches `0`. But the control block has to stay alive as long as there are *shared* or *weak pointers*, i.e. the control block will be deleted as soon as both the *shared* and *weak counter* are `0`.

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: @Tracer: Why is the `weak_ptr` necessary? Or why is a counter for `weak_ptr`s necessary?

Comment: @Tracer Suppose it didn't work like that. How would a `weak_ptr` then know whether the pointed-to object has been deleted yet?

Comment: @hvd I thought strong reference counter is used to know if managed object still exists.

Comment: @Tracer It is, but the reference count block itself needs to keep track of both the weak and strong reference counts. It only gets destroyed when both reach zero.

Comment: @Praetorian Ok. But why is important to track weak_ptr's count? That is my question. weak_ptr's are not strong pointers anyway.

Comment: @Tracer It seems we're going around in circles here. The `weak_ptr`s need to know whether the object is alive, for which you need the control block to outlive only strong references. So for destruction of the control block it's necessary that both strong and weak reference counts reach zero. Hence they must both be tracked.

Comment: @Praetorian So, control block needs to exist even if strong reference counter is 0 as long as there are any weak_ptr's who would need to check the existence of the managed object? Once no-one needs to check that (no weak_ptr's) control block is destroyed?

Answer (score 3):

Both weak and strong pointers hold a pointer to data, and a pointer to a reference count block.

When you try to convert a weak pointer to a strong pointer, you add a new strong count.  If it incremented from 0, you know that the data had already been destroyed, so you fail.  This requires access to the reference count block.

As such, the lifetime of the reference count block has to exceed the lifetime of all outstanding weak pointers.

This is ensured by reference counting the reference count block with a weak reference count.  This reference count, when reduced to zero by the last outstanding strong or weak reference going out of scope, causes the smart pointer to destroy the reference count block.

Answer (score 1):

`weak_ptr` is used for things that need a handle to the heap-object in question, but don't want to claim any ownership that would block releasing the object.  A typical example of such *things* are observers that want to know of any changes to the underlying object but don't want to keep it around if nobody else is using that object.